# TVS diodes in series causing a short

Tags: power-supply

On my board, I am using bidirectional TVS diodes for transient protection. In the schematic, the diodes are configured in bidirectional method so cathode/anode (D1) then anode/cathode (D2). During soldering, I accidentally soldered D2 the opposite way which resulted in the schematic shown.

When I powered on the board using a +5V DC supply, the power supply shorted. Even with D2 flipped, I don't understand why the supply would short as the reverse breakdown voltage is a lot higher than +5V. Flipping D2 of course fixed the problem. I am just curious as to what was the reason for the short?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2focYF7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The min breakdown voltage @1mA is about 10% more than the standoff voltage for which it is rated in the pn.

So you have two unidrectional TVS's in series with a standoff of 26V+ 14V= 28V and a diode forward drop Vf for each <1V.

### Conclusion

Maybe you put them in backwards.  Cathode bar is +ve.

Why you chose [these](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smbj_datasheet.pdf.pdf) is a mystery .

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. You accidentally wired them in parallel so that when one was reversed it put a forward biased diode across the supply which would be an almost-short.
2. One is faulty. To test this you could put a 100k resistor in parallel with each. If they're both OK you should measure 2.5 V at the junction. If not you'll get a low reading across the faulty one.

Comment: I did check that and it definitely wasn't connected in parallel. I have checked the voltage drop across the diodes with a multimeter and they are around 0.6V which makes sense.